# How to use regex to match all sentences that may have a list of stopwords inside them?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

The goal is to find all sentences that may contain a list of stopwords in between the phrase `to_match` like these:

- make wish
- make a wish
- make the a wish

```
let stopword: string[]= ["of", "the", "a"];
let to_match : string = "make wish";
let text: string = "make wish wish make a wish wish wish make the a wish make";
```

I can only match `make wish` using this regex:

```
const regex = new RegExp(`(?:\\b)$to_match(?:\\b)`, "gi");
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to do something like

```
let to_match_splitted: string[] = to_match.split(" ");
const regex = `(?:\\b)${to_match_splitted[0]}\s(${any(stopword)}?)+\s${to_match_splited[1]}(?:\\b)`;
```

With `any(stopword)` being something that match any stopword in stopword list.

And having a regex that works whatever is the length of the `to_match_splitted` with one or many stopwords between each string in the list.

Comment: What is your programming issue here? What does not work?

Comment: II can't find how to use a list of word as a variable (if it is possible) in a regex to efficiently match a pattern without using a loop, i'll edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: Can’t tell if you are asking about the regex syntax part itself here, or about how to handle your array and create a desired regex format _from_ that.

Comment: If you only want to allow one of those stop words in between the two, but also no stop word at all, then you probably want a regex like `make (of |the |a |)wish`. That would match if they were all (make, wish, and the optional stop word) separated by a single space each. If you need something else, more flexibility regarding the white space, etc. - then you’d need to be more specific in your description of the actual requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I realized it was not clear and I edited my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may create a regex like

```
/\bmake(?:\s+(?:of|the|a))*\s+wish\b/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oblpMs/2). **Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `make` - a word
- `(?:\s+(?:of|the|a))*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?:of|the|a)` - either `of`, `the` or `a` (you might want to use `an?` to also match `an`)
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `wish` - a word `wish`
- `\b` - a word boundary

In your code, you may use

```js
let stopword: string[]= ["of", "the", "a"];
let to_match : string = "make wish";
let text: string = "make wish wish make a wish wish wish make the a wish make";
const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${to_match.split(/\s+/).join("(?:\\s+(?:" + stopword.join("|") + "))*\\s+")}\\b`, "gi"); 
console.log(text.match(regex));
```

See the [online demo](https://tio.run/##bU9Nb8IwDL3zKyyLQwKo3KnQTvwBrhRB15k0UJqosdQitt/eOR0FDrvEeR969uObp1A01nPfV8QQ2PnWNV8r@TW2Nrv9GnboTrgA5JLiyHGfTqKX3eGac1HCaIY14DW/ELQ2lPgwUcf/6n/PAPM34sXKulGJWPIKVweGhgx1ElVTC1sym86rY5Z9Tu/jPUnwlWW1zMJ8qZOzs7VC9bHKBMtAmD9bPsRv1EKi1rPoQf0jcUdpaizqFIa1rqKkckbFOsmwRQ13aJ32/S8)

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for !